# Problems with IE with html() method using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with Internet Explorer browser while reading the contents of the DIV element using `jQuery('DIVID').html()` method. I insert a simple XML string to the DIV element. But when I try to read the content back using jQuery, some of the data is missing. It works fine in Firefox.

My code looks as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><div id="AJAXTESTDATA"></div>jQuery Simple Test.</p>
<script>
      var testAjax = document.getElementById("AJAXTESTDATA");
  var tes = '<SPAN id="tt"><DATA1><DATA2><DATA3><SPAN id="doc">TEST</SPAN></DATA3></DATA2></DATA1></SPAN>';
  alert("Actual Data:"+tes);
  testAjax.innerHTML = tes;
  var cbkData = jQuery('#AJAXTESTDATA').html();
  alert("Data after inserting to DIV:"+cbkData);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: 
The second alert message will display the contents of the DIV tag as below:
Data after inserting to DIV: `<SPAN id=test><SPAN id=doccase>TEST</SPAN></DATA3></DATA2></DATA1></SPAN>`
So you can see that most of the start tags are missing! So whatever tag names I use, the same is the result in IE.

Could anyone let me know the reason behind the truncation of data while reading via IE?

Kind Regards,
Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone let me know the reason behind the truncation of data while reading via IE?

There is no `c` tag in HTML 4. I assume IE is removing invalid tags in a more strict fashion than the other browsers.

If you're looking to insert the XML as *text* data (with all the tags visible), use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: C tag was an example I had used. I had updated the original question with different tag names, still the same problem in IE.

Comment: @user `DATA3` etc. are not valid HTML tags either.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Pekka IE probably be removing invalid tags. You can add `&gt;` instead of `>` and `&lt;` instead of `<`

Comment: I guess you meant using &lt with semi-colon and &gt with semi-colon. ?

Comment: Yes, isn't that what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pekka: if you use the `.text()` instead of `.html()` then your tags will not be stripped out, though I think that you will need to use `.text()` to set the value instead of `.innerHTML`.  Provided that you aren't actually expecting to display the XML data (which would not display in a sensible manner anyway) and that the AJAXTESTDATA div is actually hidden, then this will work.

jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EFSGt/2/)